# How to get last number of an array of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array. It consists of 10 arrays.

```
var arr = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
```

Every of this 10 arrays has different number of numbers. I want to get last numbers in that 10 arrays.

I have tried to do such a way:

```
var lastNums = [];
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
for (var k = 0; k < 10; k++) {
    i = arr[k].length - 1;     //This code gets number of the last number
    lastNums[j] = arr[k][i];
    j++;
}
```

But it doesn't seems to work. In Chrome Console I get:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: this means that you don't have an undefined object at `arr[k]` and not an array

Comment: Are you sure you defined arr in the same code? It should work.
BTW in your current code if your array is empty you will receive undefined

Comment: Works fine for me: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MXaxh/). You sure your array is valid?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that your array has 10 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var arr = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6,7], [8,5,6], [1,6,4,2], [8,6,3,2], [4,5,7,8], [5,4,2,2,1], [5,6,7], [4], [8,8]];
var lastNums = [];
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
    if(arr[i].length > 0){
        lastNums.push(arr[i][arr[i].length-1]);
    }
}
alert(lastNums);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have an error defining the array arr, you can do this:

```
lastNumbers = arr.map(function(k){
   return k[k.length - 1];
})
```

now the lastNumbers array will hold the last number of each array in arr. 
The good thing with using the built in array map function is that you don't 
need to care about the size of your array. The above solution works for any 
length of array.